# sets, subsets and palindrome in java

Tags: java

How do I check if a list is a subset of another list in java?  How do I check using two ListIterators to return true if the given list is a palindrome list.

Comment: I would like you to come up with approaches you have tried.  We can help you find a faster approach.  But the initiative should be yours, considering it is a homework.

Comment: it is actually part of a bigger lab assignment i am to do. i have done the rest of it but we really did not have a class on sets and subsets or palindrome it was left for us to figure out on our own thats why i am asking. thanks.

Comment: @thoroughbreed, your question shows a *total* lack of effort on your part to do this yourself.  You have shown no code, no explanation of your difficulties, nothing.  Either it is because you *haven't* tried at all, or it's because you neglected to show that effort in your question.  Either way, the point made by SidCool is completely valid.

Comment: For the first question, do you want your shorter list to have all elements in the same order as the longer list, or simply want all elements to appear also in the other? Answering this can help answering the question.

Comment: Please show us some examples of what didn't work for you. If you do that, we get a much better idea of where you are stuck. While you may have been searching all day, your question really doesn't convey that. A few snippets of code that doesn't work will go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

A palindrome is the same front to back as it is back to front. Given a list you can retrieve listIterators starting at a given index in the list. Add this to the fact that listItarators have `next()` and `previous()` methods, I am confident that you'll find a way to compare the items in the list to see if the list is in fact a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 0):

containsAll(Collection c) can solve your 1st problem.

For the 2nd problem, use reverse(List list) from Collections class. Take one iterator on the real list & other on reversed list and compare 2 lists element by element.

Comment: One could even use the equals method here :-)

Comment: Paulo, did u mean equals() for comparing elements or u mean something else?

Comment: I meant `list.equals(reversedList)` ... so you would not need to iterate element by element. (Of course, the equals-method itself would do this.)  And we should make a copy of the list first, before reversing it, since the reverse function works in-place.

Comment: Paulo, but that would check for object's reference bit. wouldn't it?

Comment: No, [List.equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is defined in terms of the equals method of the contained objects.

Answer (score 0):

To question one see [java.util.Set#containsAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29).