# Queue and Stack Homework

Tags: data-structures

I have this homework.
I want an explanation of the qustion, not a solution.

> Write an algorithm to read a text and print whether or not is a palindrome, that is the text
>   Reads the same backward as forward.

I don't understand it!

Comment: You might want to check this thread, where a discussion about palindromes is also taking place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357084/sets-subsets-and-palindrome-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Words like `rotor` are [*palindromes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome), meaning that reversing the letters of the word produces the same word.
In other words, the letters of the word are symmetric.

Comment: That said, palindromes are not limited to words.

Comment: @Andy that depends on your definition of word, now doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome would help